# How to watch installed security updates on gentoo

Tags: installation, updates, gentoo

I need to see currently installed updates and security patches on Linux Gentoo. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Gentoo Linux Security Team releases Security Advisories (GLSAs) which can be checked with glsa-check if your system is affected by the given security advisories.
You just have to sync your portage tree (emerge --sync) and then run glsa-check -l and it will tell you which known security holes you have and how to solve them.

`glsa-check` is part of the `gentoolkit`.

And very important is [Maintenance](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Gentoo_maintenance). This article shows how to keep your system up to date and clean.